# Google Spreadsheet pop up input dialog

Tags: javascript, popup, documentation, spreadsheet

Anyone knows how to bring up a pop-up input dialog window when maybe clicking on a cell or hitting enter on that cell? The requirement is to accept a 9 digits number in a text field, then choose from 4 categories namely 1,2,3 or 4 as radio buttons. When the user presses enter, the cell in question will be filled with a background color depending on the category and the 9 digits number would be the last portion of a URL so that the cell can link to the item's webpage.

I am using this syntax to obtain the linkable cell content:

=HYPERLINK( CONCATENATE( "http://www.website.com/findItem=",A5, ); A5)

That part works fine, but I don't know how to make the pop up window appear. Anyone?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so its not possible because there is currently no way to trigger a script when clicking on a cell according to

stackoverflow.com/questions/21352603/how-to-display-form-or-dialog-when-user-clicds-in-a-google-spreadsheet-cell

Will try a google form instead and see how that works.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to create `<div z-index=...>`. z-index with non-zero value will bring your div to the front of the main page, creating a "window".

Comment: I don't follow... Lets just narrow it down to triggering a pop up window to appear whenever a cell in a Google Spreadsheet is clicked. Is that possible? How?